# Xamarin, Android. Everytime I run the app on device, the application is unistalled and then installed again.

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

Is very annoying because **I´ve to login in Facebook in order to use the app**. So every time I want to test a new code implementation I need to login on Facebook. If the app would not get uninstalled, the credentials will persist and when I run the app I wont need to login. It also happens when I run it with the emulator, but I prefer using a device.

**Does anyone know how to avoid the uninstall?**

I´m using Xamarin on Mac developing for android, and the device is a Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini.

Comment: It's not possible to avoid the uninstall as far as I know, but have you tried the "Preserve application data/cache on device between deploys" option?  It's in Tools > Options > Xamarin if you're using Visual Studio.

Comment: @user1132457 I´m using Xamarin Studio, and I have not seen any option like that one. I don´t know if I´m missing something.

Comment: If you're on Windows, it's still under Tools > Options, on OS X look under Xamarin Studio > Preferences.  Then on either one look for Projects > Android.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the setting: http://cl.ly/image/1O0m3Y2w3W3p

Comment: I can confirm that the setting mentioned has resolved this exact issue for me - I no longer have to log in to Facebook every time I recompile and run my app.

Comment: Yes! @JoelMalone I upvoted the comments waiting for him/her to put the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to project option->Android Buid -> Linker -> Linker Behaviour-> set it link SDK assembly only.

Comment: 2021 Not working!